# Connection between C#app and a node.js

Tags: c#, node.js, xamarin, websocket

I make a simple test to try to connect a C# app to a node js server with web socket. I use this following nugget package SocketIoClientDotNet (https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet/).

My app code :

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client;
using Quobject.EngineIoClientDotNet.Modules;

namespace TestWebSocket
{
    [Activity(Label = "TestWebSocket", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        private Socket socket;


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {   
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);



            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            button.Click += delegate {
                Console.WriteLine("Step1");
                socket = IO.Socket("http://localhost:8080");
                socket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
                {                    
                    Console.WriteLine("Step3");
                });
            };
        }
    }
}
```

My nodejs code :

```
var http = require('http');

// Chargement du fichier index.html affiché au client
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end("content");
});

// Chargement de socket.io
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// Quand un client se connecte, on le note dans la console
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

   console.log('Un client est connecté(e)';    

});

server.listen(8080);
```

When I click on button (with Android emulator) only I just watch "Step1" in the console and there isn't any errors indication. I don't know why "Step3" doesn't work (that means that app doesn't try to connect to server !).

Can you help me!

Comment: why the android tag?

Comment: @AmanGrover The C# code utilizes Xamarin, that's why he added the android tag. I updated the question.

Comment: you need to use the IP or FQDN of your server, not localhost.  localhost will refer back to your Android device/emulator

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working!!! And I understand why!